# Why JS doesn't coerce the value of i in a "for in loop"?

Tags: javascript, coercion

Given the two functions (with the expected output of `//d`):

```
function fearNotLetter(str) {

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    let code = str.charCodeAt(i)
    if (code !== str.charCodeAt(0) + i) {
      return String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(0) + i)
    }
  }
  return undefined
}

fearNotLetter("abce");

// d
```

And

```
function fearNotLetter(str) {

  for (let i in str) {
    let code = str.charCodeAt(i)
    if (code !== str.charCodeAt(0) + i) {
      return String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(0) + i)
    }
  }
  return undefined

}

fearNotLetter("abce");

// ϊ
```

I discovered that the value of `i` is coerced to a String using the `for...in` loop. In my understanding, the if statement fails, because the value of `i` is no longer a number, therefore the sum can't be done. 
My question is, why doesn't JS coerce `i` back to a number in the if statement `(str.charCodeAt(0) + i )`? And allow the sum to be done the same way as he `for...loop`?
Is it because, once `i`is coerced inside the funct, then it can't be coerced again?

Comment: No. That doesn't mean that they don't exist. But in this specific case this is an odd behavior that I'm trying to understand..

Comment: That is the expected behaviour, the `+` operator will perform concatenation if any of the variables or literals is a string.

Comment: "*the value of `i` is coerced to a String*" - not exactly. The `i` value is the property *name*, which has been a string from the beginning. There is no coercion occurring.  "*why doesn't JS coerce i back to a number*" - because `+` is string concatenation. And `!==` is a type-sensitive comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first function you set the type of `i` to `number` when you initialized it to a number. In the second function `i` is a key to an iterable so it means it's type is `string`. There hasn't been type conversion at all.

Comment: Ok I got it. Because I have a number with ```str.charCodeAt(0)``` and ```i``` is a string, the ```+``` operator will perform concat. Therefore the result of ```str.charCodeAt(0) + i``` is = to "970". That bugs the code.

Answer (score 1):

*Basically that's the [coercion rule](https://delapouite.com/ramblings/javascript-coercion-rules.html)*. As you can see in the *table `+`*, a `String` + a `Number`, the `Number` will always be *implicitly* coerced to `String`.

The intuition is, both `String` and `Number` have the `+` operator, but the `Number` will always be able to be coerced to a `String`, whereas not all `String` is *(can be coerced to)* a `Number`.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

`str.charCodeAt(parseInt(i, 10))`

Comment: The point is not to debug the code. My point here is to understand what is under the hood...

Comment: I read some stuff, but nothing mentioned coercion. That's why I decided to ask...

Comment: @TiagoRuivo Oh sorry for misunderstanding. I guess some others have answered that for you :)